# check in js whether css color property accepts 'inherit' value

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to check in javascript whether the browser accepts the value 'inherit' for the css color property, i.e. whether `object.stye.color='inherit'` will not cause an error (It does in IE 7).

Answer (score 0):

This might help in detection of css properties: [Css Properties Detection](http://www.sitepoint.com/detect-css3-property-browser-support/)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I use a trick for `rgba` colours:

```
try {elem.style.background = "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)";}
catch(e) {elem.style.background = "#cccccc";}
```

You can easily adapt this to your problem:

```
try {elem.style.color = "inherit";} // or "currentColor" which is synonymous here
catch(e) {elem.style.color = "red";} // or whatever fallback you want
```

Alternatively, try this instead:

```
if( typeof getComputedStyle == "undefined")
    getComputedStyle = function(elm) {return elm.currentStyle;}
elem.style.color = getComputedStyle(elem.parentNode).color;
```

This will get the computed style (`currentStyle` in older IE) of the parent node, which is essentially the same as `inherit`ing.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please Accept the answer.